# How to use bean that is already configured in another .xml file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to follow [this example](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/preauthorize-postauthorize-in-spring-security) about Spring Security and adapt it to my needs but I'm having troubles with its configuration

I have a `LoginService` that looks like this:

```
// This example does not make sense of course but I'm just
// trying to make it work with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
// and see an exception or something that lets me know that
// it is actually working ..

public class LoginService {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoginService.class.getName());

    private AdministratorRepository administratorRepository;

    public LoginService(DSLContext ctx) {       
        this.administratorRepository = new AdministratorRepository(ctx);
    }

    @Transactional
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public void login(String userId, String password) {     
        LOGGER.debug("Login for " + userId);        
        this.administratorRepository.login(userId, password);   
    }

}
```

and I am already initalizing this class in my **applicationContext-jooq.xml** like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mz_db" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure Spring's transaction manager to use a DataSource -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure jOOQ's TransactionProvider as a proxy to Spring's transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionProvider"
    class="com.mz.server.web.SpringTransactionProvider">
</bean>

<!-- Configure jOOQ's ConnectionProvider to use Spring's TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy,
     which can dynamically discover the transaction context -->
<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure the DSL object, optionally overriding jOOQ Exceptions with Spring Exceptions -->
<bean id="dsl" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
    <constructor-arg ref="config" />
</bean>

<!-- Invoking an internal, package-private constructor for the example
     Implement your own Configuration for more reliable behaviour -->
<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
    <property name="SQLDialect"><value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">POSTGRES_9_4</value></property>
    <property name="connectionProvider" ref="connectionProvider" />
    <property name="transactionProvider" ref="transactionProvider" />
</bean>

<!-- BEGIN Services -->

<bean id="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="dsl" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- END Services -->
```

My problem is that I want `loginService` to be managed by Spring Security as well. This is my **applicationContext-security.xml**:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <http auto-config="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager >
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

<!-- <beans:bean name="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService"/> -->

</beans:beans>
```

If I comment out

```
<beans:bean name="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService"/>
```

I'm getting the error that there's no default constructor - which is true since this class is **1.** Already instantiated and **2.** Requires a `DSLContext` object as constructor parameter.

If I let it commented out just nothing happens. No exception of warning is shown. `@PreAuthorize` appears to be getting ignored ..

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are the `applicationContext-security` and `applicationContext-jooq` loaded in the same context?

Comment: @M.Deinum To be honest I can't answer that. How can I tell if they are? Basically **applicationContext-security.xml** should only contain Spring-related beans whereas **applicationContext-jooq** describes just the way my database connection works. How can I tell if they're loaded in the same context?

Comment: If they are both loaded with the `COntextLoaderListener` it will work if one of them is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` it will not work. Another thing is you don't have an interface so you might need to set `proxy-target-class` to `true` on the `global-method-security` element.

Comment: I also suggest read on how Spring works and especially how configuration for an `ApplicationContext` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add constructor injection into your XML configuration for the `LoginService`.  Do you autowire `DSLContext`, too?

This line in your XML is invoking the *default* constructor:

```
<beans:bean name="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService"/>
```

If you want to do constructor injection of the `DSLContext` it'd look like this:

```
<bean name="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService">
    <constructor-arg ref="dslContext"/>
</bean>
```

This assumes that the bean factory also has a bean for your `DSLContext`.

You can also try going all annotation or XML configuration, but not mixing and matching.

Comment: The `DSLContext` gets passed as constructor argument in **applicationContext-jooq.xml** (see above) - do you mean that by *constructor injection*?

Comment: See my updated answer: It has exactly what constructor injection looks like when you do it correctly.

Comment: I don't understand. This is what I am doing in **applicationContext-jooq.xml**?

Comment: Look the bean factory says you got it wrong. Check your assumptions. You make no progress if you just assume you got everything right and Spring is persecuting you. There's a configure where you ask for a default Cyprus where there is none. Fix it.

Comment: Okay. But my problem is not that I don't know how to pass the `DSLContext` to `LoginService`. My problem is that I don't know how I can e.g. reuse the bean `<bean id="dsl" ...>` that is already described in **applicationContext-jooq.xml** in my **applicationContext-security.xml**. What you are suggesting is that I simply copy & paste the configuration from **-jooq.xml** to **-security.xml** and use `dsl` the way I'm already using it. My question aims at trying to avoid having the exact same configuration for a bean in two different config-files.

Comment: If you load both XML files into a single bean factory, why must you have the same configuration for a bean in both?  The second file can just use the reference to the bean that was created when the first file was loaded.  Another way would be to put common beans in a third file and have the other two import it.